# Create a list from another list with R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of letters l

```
[1] a b c
[2] b c a b
```

and a vector v of letter too

```
[1] a
[2] b
```

My object is to take the letters of the vector v one by one and creating a new list that contains all the letter appearing after that letter.
For example
I take the first letter of v "a" and I create the list of letter appearing after "a" , And I got this :

```
[1] b c
[2] b
```

After i take the second letter or v which is "b"
and I add to the list :

```
[3] c   
[4] c a b
```

So the final result is :

```
[1] b c
[2] b
[3] c   
[4] c a b
```

I don't know how to do this, it seems complicated.

I have also a list of vector with this format

```
[[1]]
[1] a
[2] b 
[3] c
[[2]]
[1] e
[2] g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nested `lapply`:

```
lapply(v, function(v, l) lapply(l, function(x, v) {
  if (!(v %in% x)) return(x) #the case of no match
  x[-seq_len(which.max(x == v))]
}, v = v), l = l)
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "b" "c"
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "b"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] "c"
#
#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] "c" "a" "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using lapply.

```
dat <- list( c("a", "b", "c"), c("b", "c", "a", "b"))
v <- c("a", "b")

result <- list()
for (l in v) {
  result[[l]] <- lapply(dat, function(z) z[(which(z == l)[1] + 1):length(z)])
}
result
```